What is SRT division algorithm?
I have been studying the IEEE-754 standard and came across the information that floating-point division uses the SRT algorithm, which is currently the fastest and most accurate method. However, I have been unable to find any comprehensive articles or references on this topic.
Could you please explain the steps of the SRT algorithm? What principles should I follow if I want to calculate, for example, 1234 ÷ 56?

Did you try wikepedia? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_algorithm#SRT_division

@MotiNK Yes. But that was insufficient.

@D.W. I edited the post to sound more specific.

Thank you for the edit, that is much clearer.  Wikipedia contains references where it appears you can learn more; I would suggest trying to track them down and read them.
